# java.io.filenotfoundexception downloading zip and extracting it

Tags: java, download, unzip

I made a small program to download a zip file from a direct link and after that extract all contents of it in the same directory.
It doesn't download anything and it also doesn't extract.
This is what I have so far:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class Main {

    static String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/uml938guklfvo7r/Tekst.zip?dl=1";
    static int lastSlashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
    static String filename= url.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1, url.length() - 5);
    static String filepath = "C:";
    private static final int BUFFER = 4096;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            URL website = new URL(url);
            ReadableByteChannel rbc;
            rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
            new File(filepath + filename).createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath + filename);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

        try {
            unzip(filepath + filename, filepath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        // iterates over entries in the zip file
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }

    private static void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
        Line 68>> BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        bos.close();
    }  
}
```

Here is the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Tekst.txt (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at main.Main.extractFile(Main.java:68)
    at main.Main.unzip(Main.java:55)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: @EelLee I edited my main post.

Comment: So you can see that the error is "C:\Tekst.txt (access is denied)", which system are you running - Windows, Linux? Maybe you simply don't have permission to this folder? Please try to provide all the helpful information in your post - show the line which throws the exception, tell us what OS are you working on, etc.

Comment: @EelLee line 66 is BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath)); I added << line 66 next to id, but you didn't see it. I am running on Windows.

Comment: OK, and are you logged as an admin or some other user? Try simply creating file in the C:\ main folder in the Windows Explorer - can you do it from there? If not, can you create a file in the C:\Users\[your_username]\ ?

Comment: I can create folders in the C:/ directory and I even have a program that creates a folder and extracts a downloaded zip in that folder, but I can't get it done when I try it for myself. BTW. I downloaded that program with it's source.

Comment: Then I guess, looking more at your code, the answer is even simpler, I don't think you even create the file. You are operating on the file path, but the file does not exist yet.

Comment: @EelLee That could be the answer, but do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Use a destination directory that you can write to, it's that simple.  writing anything to "C:" directly is a bad idea.

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx why do you keep editing this question? Now it even contains a message in a not-english language (I deduct it's dutch, from the google translate). 
And you keep getting "access denied", so I think you don't have the permission. Because this code worked after changes described in my answer.

Comment: jtahlborn I will try that. @EelLee Sorry for editing, but where would I else show eveyone the code I have and the error I get?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this file is simply not created yet. You can create it with

```
new File(yourFilepath).createNewFile()
```

and you need to do it **before** you invoke

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath + filename);
```

which throws the exception. Then it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I tried to add that piece of code and have an error again. I updated the main post with the code I have now and the error I got from it

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx edited the answer, you need to create the file *before* you start to do anything with it ;-)

Comment: no you don't, FileOutputStream will create the file automatically.

Comment: @jtahlborn well I had the same exceptions author had, introduced changes mentioned above, which worked, so... And, BTW, this question has been edited like 4 times, at least once after my answer, so it can be no longer valid. But at the time of answering, I checked the same code myself and it worked.

Comment: @EelLee Are you able to give me the code you had working, so I can see what I did wrong?